# nHibernate BulkInsert Identity column?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sqlbulkcopy, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, identity-column

Question: I'm bulk-inserting data from XML using nHibernate (fluent)

I read the XML file into a datatable, then create a List from it.
Afterwards, I run BulkInsert on that list.

Like this:

```
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982295/saving-1000-records-to-the-database-at-a-time
    public static void BulkInsert(List<dynamic> ls)
    {
        //List<DB.Tables.T_Users> ls = new List<DB.Tables.T_Users>();
        // Read from DataTable


        var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

        //using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())

        // http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/10/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernates-stateless-sessions/
        using (IStatelessSession session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.SetBatchSize(ls.Count);
                foreach (var objThisItem in ls)
                {
                    //session.SaveOrUpdate(objThisItem);
                    session.Insert(objThisItem);
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine, just that the User-ID (Auto-ID) is newly assigned.

This is T_User

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_User](
    [USR_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USR_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [USR_Prename] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [USR_User] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [USR_Password] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [USR_Language] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [USR_Hash] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [USR_isLDAPSync] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [USR_Domaene] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [USR_Hide] [bit] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [USR_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

How can I insert the users and preserve the IDs with nHibernate ?
I need to insert the user-group mapping afterwards, so this will fail if IDs change...

.NET & SqlClient has SqlBulkCopy
and

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity`

for that.

But what has nHibernate ?

And while I am at it, what does it have for

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a temporary Sessionfactory. Assuming you have

```
private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(Action<Configuration> addconfigure)
```

and code

```
var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory(config =>
    ((SimpleValue)config.GetClassMapping(typeof(User)).Identifier)
        .IdentifierGeneratorStrategy = "assigned");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try correct mapping with:

```
mapping => mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned()
```

Comment: But ... Id(x => x.BE_ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("BE_ID"); is fundamentally correct, I want it to be a generated idendity (later on, one can create users in the BackOffice). I just want to switch off auto-assigning for the initial table population.